# How can I run a ruby program as its own command?

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line

It is possible to put the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` at the top and run `chmod +x myProgram.rb` to run it from the terminal by doing something like `./myProgram.rb`.

This requires the path to the `.rb` file. I am trying to run the program by just typing `myProgram` into a terminal.

Comment: Make it executable and put it somewhere in your `$PATH` (the usual place is _/usr/local/bin_).

Comment: The default .bashrc on some linux distros also adds `$HOME/bin` to the path if it exists.  I normally symlink things into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an alternative that I tend to prefer. Instead of balooning my `PATH` variable, I put a single folder such as `~/bin` in my `PATH`. Then I create symlinks from here to any executables I have in odd locations. E.g. `ln -s /path/to/myProgram.rb ~/bin/myProgram.rb`

Comment: I have a dir like this for little scripts and things I have written over time. These are mostly ruby and with the `#!` and executable you can also omit the `.rb`

Comment: Personal preference, I like to keep the file extensions :-)

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz When I run `ln -s ~/bin/myProgram.rb /path/to/myProgram.rb`, it gives me an error `ln: ~/bin/myProgram.rb: File exists`, but when I go into `~/bin`, there isn't anything named `myProgram.rb`

Comment: @Mining15 I got it backwards, it's ln -s existing_file new_link_file. Updated my response to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory to the PATH variable. When you type a command in *nix, it tries to look up the command in all the directories in PATH.

Here is a random article explaning how https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux.